# website redirection to mobile site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I need help in redirecting visitor to depending on device they use.

PC: http://example.com/filename
Mobile: http://mobile.example.com/filename

I tried with java script notice 1 issue when user enters url example .com/filename it is redirecting to mobile index page instead of page user wanted.

main issue i noticed is url entered by user is not captured. 
Please help me how to do it

1. If user is using PC he should remain on main website and if using mobile device he should redirect to mobile site.
2. Url entered by user should be captured

Answer (score 0):

I won't be specifically answering your question, but it's no longer that "good practice" to separate content for mobile and desktop devices.

In these days of CSS3, HTML5 there are lots of better ways to accomplish fully responsive webpage than deviding the content.

I understand that there might be reasons why you need to do it this way (finished project that would be hard to reconstruct, etc.) but if it's not too late, think about it.

This answer could be also useful for people who don't know all possibilities on responsive web pages field.